# OpenCV - SimpleBlobDetector - Issues with area thresholding

Tags: opencv, image-processing, blob

I am using OpenCV -  SimpleBlobDetector to detect blobs (black colored) in a binary image.
When the **minArea** is set to low values (50 to 100), the algorithm return most of the expected blobs. As shown below (observe the area circled in blue):

[image]

However, when the **minArea** is raised to > 200. The algorithm returns non-blob areas as blobs. Please check the image below, observe the area circled in blue.

My questions:
Is the algorithm returning white colored region as blobs? (I don't think so).
I have set both **filterByColor** and **filterByConvexity** to false.
Could you explain why those two blobs inside the blue circle are returned. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you add your original input image and an expected output result?

Comment: @nathancy The above images are original but with blobs overlaid.

Comment: You have blue drawings and red circles on your images those are not the original

Comment: No it makes a blob from those multiple black areas. Do an erosion on the image before blob detection. It removes those little black pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You require a simple contour detection in this case instead of Blob detection. Because the Blob detection also tries to group the smaller nearby contours to form a blob. So we have two options here:

- Tweak the blob detection parameters to disable the merging of smaller
  contours.
- Use simple contour detection and filter the contours using
  `cv2.contourArea`.

I would prefer the second approach in this case, as using the Blob Detector would only increase the complexity in this case (there are multiple thresholding operations happening under the hood along with other merging routines as well). We can follow the following steps to filter the contours(blobs):

1. Inverse threshold the image, because generally the contours to be detected should have `255` grayscale intensity, but in your input image, the contour are black(`0` gray scale value).
2. Then we can use `cv2.findContours()` methods on the binary image obtained in step 1.
3. From step 2 you will get a list of contours. Now we can iterate the list and filter out the smaller contours using `cv2.contourArea()`.
4. From step 3 we would have a list of contours whose area are greater than the defined threshold. Now you can draw circle around that contours or simply draw the contour using `cv2.drawContours` method.